# Unity3D oval wheels/cilinders

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, scale, models

I have inserted a wheel into my game and some reason it has come out as an oval, even when the scale is set to 1, 1, 1. How can I fix this? Granted that I can just increase the Y scale, however it then messes up the rotation.

[image: oval wheel]

(Note that you can see the wheel models are circle down below)

Thanks

James

Comment: Your wheels also inherit the scale from Body and CarPrefabEmpty. Have you checked those scales?

Comment: Thanks! you was right... The scale of the body prefab was out